# Deletion from Binary Tree C++

Tags: c++, oop, binary-tree

I have written a delete function in a binary tree implementation and am having trouble when a node has two children. It seems to copy the data I need into the node to be deleted, but when I go to delete the successor node, I get a seg fault.

Class Def

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Set
{
private:
    class Node
    {
        public:
            T data;
            Node *left;
            Node *right;
            Node(T key)
            {
                this->data = key;
                this->left = this->right = nullptr;
            }
    };
    Node *root; int size;

public:
    Set();
    ~Set();
    void insert(T key);
    Node *insert(Node *&ptr, T key);
    void remove(T key);
    Node *remove(Node *&, T key);
    bool contains(T key);
    bool contains(Node *&ptr, T key);
    void cutDown(Node *ptr);
    int getSize();
    void print();
    void print(Node *ptr);
};
```

Construct

```
template <typename T>
Set<T>::Set()
{
    root = nullptr; size = 0;
}
```

Insert

```
template <typename T>
void Set<T>::insert(T key)
{
   // std::cout << "inserted...\n";
    insert(root, key);
}

template <typename T>
typename Set<T>::Node *Set<T>::insert(Node *&ptr, T key)
{
    if (contains(key) == false)
    {
        if (ptr == nullptr)
        {
            ++size;
            Node *temp = new Node(key);
            ptr = temp;
            return ptr;
        }
        else 
        {
            Node *temp = ptr;
            if (key > temp->data)
            {
                temp->right = insert(temp->right, key);
            }
            else if (key < temp->data) 
            {
                temp->left = insert(temp->left, key);
            }
        }
    }
    else  
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Remove

```
template <typename T>
void Set<T>::remove(T key)
{
    remove(root, key);
    std::cout << "deleted...\n\n";
    --size;
}

template <typename T>
typename Set<T>::Node *Set<T>::remove(Node *&ptr, T key)
{
    //std::cout << "data = " << root->right->data << "\n";
    if (key > ptr->data)
    {
        std::cout << "greater...\n";
        ptr->right = remove(ptr->right, key);
    }
    else if (key < ptr->data)
    {
        std::cout << "less...\n";
        ptr->left = remove(ptr->left, key);
    }
    else  
    {
        if (!ptr->left && !ptr->right) //no children
        {
            std::cout << "case 1...\n";
            delete ptr;
            ptr = nullptr;
            //--size;
        }
        else if (ptr->left && ptr->right) //two children
        {
            std::cout << "case 2...\n";
            Node *child = ptr->right;
            //std::cout << "child data: " << child->data << "\n";
            Node *p = child;
            while (child->left != nullptr)
            {
                child = child->left;
            }
            ptr->data = child->data;
            //std::cout << "data = " << p->data << "\n";
            std::cout << "next data: " << p->left->data << "\n";
            p->left = remove(p->left, child->data);
            //child = nullptr;
        }
        else                             //one child
        {
            std::cout << "case 3...\n";
            Node *node = ptr;
            Node *hold = (ptr->left)? ptr->left : ptr->right;
            node = hold;
            delete hold;
            //--size;
           // return ptr;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Contains

```
template <typename T>
bool Set<T>::contains(T key)
{
    return contains(root, key);
}

template <typename T>
bool Set<T>::contains(Node *&ptr, T key)
{
   // std::cout << ptr << "\n";
    Node *hold = ptr;
    while (hold != nullptr)
    {
        if (hold->data == key)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
            if (hold->data > key)
            {
                hold = hold->left;
            }
            else  
            {
                hold = hold->right;
            }
        
    }
    return false;
}
```

getSize just returns size.

Comment: Your recursion goes on forever if it doesn't find the specified key, you don't check for null pointers so will eventually get a seg fault. I'm guessing that when you do `ptr->left = remove(ptr->right, key);` that's exactly what's happening, the key you're looking for no longer exists so you recurse until it crashes

Comment: @AlanBirtles When I remove an element with two children and print the resulting tree, I can see where the successor was copied to the element to be 'deleted' and also the successor node itself. The line you highlighted is me trying to remove that successor so there arent two copies(as I'm sure you know). That successor hasn't been freed at the point of that lines execution(as far as I'm aware).

Comment: I added a trivial test that also happens to be what is giving me the seg fault, at the S.remove(5) line.

Comment: We can't debug your code for you as you haven't provided a [mre]

Comment: Apologies, Alan. The question has been updated. I included all pertinent code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: when you delete `hold` you don't remove it from the tree, leaving a dangling pointer which will be what causes your crash